# How to find all Document Libraries / Lists that have InfoPath enabled in C#?

Tags: sharepoint-server, document-library, infopath, migration, sharepoint-on-prem

Looking for C# code to find all document libraries and lists that have InfoPath enabled on them. Sites are 2010/2013 SharePoint sites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write to console or save into file. It list all lists and libraries where is used Template with XSN:

```
asnp *sharepoint*
cls

#$ct = @()
$wa = get-spwebapplication https://sharepoint.dev.cz
$wa

foreach($site in $wa.sites)
{
    foreach($Web in $site.AllWebs)
    {
        foreach($list in $Web.Lists)
        {
            if($list.AllowContentTypes -eq $true)             
            {
                if(-not ($systemlibs -Contains $list.Title))
                {
                    if ($list.AllowContentTypes -eq $true)
                    {                           
                        foreach ($contenttype in $list.ContentTypes)
                        {
                            if($contenttype.DocumentTemplateUrl -like "*.xsn")
                            {
                                $ctObject = New-Object -TypeName PSObject
                                $ctObject | Add-Member -Name 'WebTitle' -MemberType Noteproperty -Value $web.Title
                                $ctObject | Add-Member -Name 'WebUrl' -MemberType Noteproperty -Value $web.URL
                                $ctObject | Add-Member -Name 'ListTitle' -MemberType Noteproperty -Value $list.Title                                
                                $ctObject | Add-Member -Name 'ContentType' -MemberType Noteproperty -Value $contenttype.Name   
                                $ctObject | Add-Member -Name 'ContentTypeUrl' -MemberType Noteproperty -Value $contenttype.DocumentTemplateUrl 
                                #$ct += $ctObject                      
                                Write-Host $ctObject
                            }
                        }                           
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

#$ct | export-csv "filename.csv"
```

Comment: This worked! Used this logic in C# CSOM code and works fine. Thanks!

Comment: Further, how can I get details of the info path form that is used?

Comment: What info you are expecting?

Comment: Any identifier for the InfoPath form. Like name of the file or url.

Scenario: I have a Library that uses multiple InfoPath forms. After migration need to see if they exist in the target SharePointt online site. So need to match the files. 
Currently trying to get the File using url and then filename. Works well so far. 
Open to other ideas

Comment: but with my code you have the name in the last column "ContentTypeUrl" there is something like "/library/TemplateName.xsn" that's name.If there are more templates, there will be listed more templates.

Comment: or you want to get info about created files in library not the template?

Comment: No just the name of templates. That should do.

Comment: my script do this